# subscribing to property changes in View throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, xaml, reactiveui

I have code that looks similar to the following

ViewModel:

```
public class VM : ReactiveObject
{
    public double _number;
    public double Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _number, value); }
    }
}
```

View:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, IViewFor<VM>
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = new VM();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.ViewModel.Number)
            .Subscribe(n => Debug.WriteLine(n));
    }

    public VM ViewModel
    {
        get { return (VM)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(VM), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (VM)value; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Number = ViewModel.Number + 1;
    }
}
```

When I run it I get an ArgumentNullException on the "WhenAnyValue" line.

This seems to follow every example of usage I can find.  I'm at a loss here.

Comment: This is a Windows 8.1 app, so unfortunately I'd have to post an awful lot of code for it to be fully working.  I'll put up a quick Github repository for it.

Comment: For the sample sln go here. https://github.com/ghotiphud/ViewWhenAnyError

Comment: Can you post the call stack?

Comment: Call stack: https://gist.github.com/ghotiphud/d59b53fa880d79d92606

Comment: VM is set (not null)? `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` is defined? **double** `_number` would default to 0, so that isn't anything to worry about. Is `value` null?

Comment: The null exception stems from some sort of reflection on properties in ReactiveUI.  It's hard to say why this is triggering an exception, since it's basically copied from the RxUI_QCon example.  I'm going to give that example one more look...

Answer (score 1):

Make ViewModel a DependencyProperty and your problems will go away

Comment: I've updated the ViewModel to a DependencyProperty, but unfortunately I'm still seeing the same issue.  See the updated code above.

Comment: At this point I'm thinking this might be something specific to it being a Windows 8.1 app. I put identical code into a WPF app and it works.  I've pushed all of this to https://github.com/ghotiphud/ViewWhenAnyError

Comment: The WPF app even works when the ViewModel isn't a DependencyProperty.

Comment: Is the difference in behavior expected on Windows 8.1?

Comment: Nope. Can you file a bug?